# Error: Could not find or load main class2

Tags: java

Вопрос задавался уже много раз :)
Ответы на такие же вопросы были:
1. задан package, соответственно запускаемый класс надо указывать с учетом того что написано в package
2. Необходимо указывать параметр -classpath при запуске из консоли.

Я все эти моменты проверил - но почему то не работает.

Тестовый проект maven на IntelliJ Idea

Проект немного сложнее Hello,
В проекте присутствует небольшой код - вызов jar библиотеки MQTT
Структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Содержимое pom.xml
<groupId>MqttPublishSample</groupId>
<artifactId>MqttPublishSample</artifactId>
```

Содержимое MqttPublishSample.java:

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
public class MqttPublishSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

На Idea подключил библиотеку MQTT от eclipse через File/Project Structure/Modules
Idea все замечательно скомпилировала, запустила, все работает.

А вот попытка запустить все это через консоль кончилась неудачно
Запускать пробовал по всякому - но все равно неудачно.

```
g:
cd G:\eclipse\test5\target\classes
java -Xdiag -classpath "G:\eclipse\test5\libs\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar";"G:\eclipse\test5\target\classes\MqttPublishSample.class" MqttPublishSample
```

Подскажите пожалуйста - в чем может быть проблема ?
package в файле нет, на всякий случай пробовал запускать main.java.MqttPublishSample - с тем же успехом

Comment: Почему то нигде об этом не написано - оказалось что параметр после -classpath надо заключать в кавычки, вот так работает:<br>

java.exe -classpath "G:\eclipse\test6\out\production\test6;G:\eclipse\test6\libs\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar" MqttPublishSample

Comment: Проголосовал за переоткрытие в связи с [обнаружившимися обстоятельствами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7550/213987), правда обращаю внимание топикстартера, что у него в вопросе кавычки были и в ответе тоже кавычки есть - в чём же тогда разница? Если она есть - надо раскрыть подробнее.